# What is the correct way to obtain the position of a quartile and its value?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying statistics, specifically position measurements.

The problem is that I have seen many ways to calculate the quartile, quintile, percentile, decile, etc.

The main formulas that I have seen to calculate the POSITION of a quartile are:

$\frac{(n+1)i}{4}$ and $\frac{ni}{4}$, where $n =$ number of data, $i =$ number of quartile$(1, 2, 3)$

Some websites claim that one formula is to calculate odd data and the other in pairs. However, in many exercises, they use the formula (n + 1) q / 4 for a number of even data and odd numbers of data, without distinction.

What has given me success in the exercises (so far), is to obtain the POSITION of the quartile with the formula $\frac{(n+1)i}{4}$, without distinguishing between odd and even data, and to obtain the VALUE of the quartile I have two options:

- If the position of the quartile is a decimal, the VALUE will be the average between the two closest integers.
- If the position of the quartile is an INTEGER, the VALUE will be the data that is in that position.

And I have the same doubt, with the formulas for quintile, decile and percentile.

But my recently exposed methodology has worked well for me, however I come to ask, Is the way I am getting the POSITION and VALUE of the position measurements correct or not correct at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no one 'correct way'. Definitions differ from textbook to textbook. If you are taking a course, try to get a clear idea what you textbook and class notes say to do. Then after the course, you can choose your favorite method. See my answer for several methods in common use.

Comment: BruceET has given an excellent answer.  Adapting a remark from Numerical Recipes (from a related subject), if you care about the difference between these definitions you are probably up to no good.  In his example the lower quartile is somewhere in the range $95-96$ depending on the exact definition you use.  How much does that matter?  We could add $1,000,000$ to all the observations $96$ and above in his dataset and the range of answers would grow enormously, but they would still be between $95$ and $1,000,096$

Comment: Related question, answer, and discussion at the stats.stackexchange.com question [_Finding Quartiles in R_](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134229/301025).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data:** If you are finding the lower quartile of a sample, you should know that
various textbooks and software programs use slightly different definitions.
Roughly speaking, the lower quartile separates the lower quarter of the
sorted data from the upper three quarters. Differences among the specific
definitions arise most clearly when the sample size is not divisible by $4.$

For example, consider the sample of $n = 25$ observations shown below sorted
from smallest to largest.

```
x
 [1]  66  82  86  91  95  95  96  96  96  97 101 104
[13] 104 106 106 107 108 108 109 111 111 112 112 120
[25] 125
```

The median is at 104 (the 13th observation in order). The 7th observation is 96.
it has 'not more than 25% of the observations below': precisely, $6/25 = 24\%;$
it has 'not more than 75% of the observations above': precisely, $16/25 = 60\%$ (taking tied values into account). So many textbooks would say the lower
quartile is 96.

According to the default method in R statistical software the lower quartile
(25th percentile) is 96 as shown below:

```
quantile(x, .25)
25% 
 96
```

However, for compatibility with other software, R has nine different 'types'
of definitions that you can request. They make different compromises when
the sample size is not divisible by 4 and when there are ties in the vicinity
of the lower quartile. Here are a few that give different answers:

```
quantile(x, .25, type=3)
25% 
 95 
quantile(x, .25, type=4)
 25% 
95.25 
quantile(x, .25, type=5)
 25% 
95.75   
quantile(x, .25, type=8)
 25% 
95.66667
```

Differences among the definitions of quantiles (including quartiles) may seem important in small datasets, but in practical applications, quantiles are most often
used for very large datasets where the differences are usually not consequential.

---

**Continuous distributions:** If you are dealing with continuous probability distributions, then the
25th percentile is usually unique. Here are the lower quartiles of
the distributions $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=1)$ and $\mathsf{Exp}(rate = 1):$

```
> qnorm(.25, 0, 1)
[1] -0.6744898
> qexp(.25, 1)
[1] 0.2876821
```

---

**Discrete distributions:** For discrete distributions such as binomial and Poisson, it is not usually
possible to find an integer value that cuts off exactly the lower quarter of
the probability in the distribution. Below are results for
$\mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p=1/3)$ and $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 5).$ The
R functions `pbinom` and `ppois` designate CDFs of binomial and Poisson
distributions respectively.

```
qbinom(.25, 5, 1/3)
[1] 1                # 25th percentile is 1
pbinom(1, 5, 1/3)
[1] 0.4609053        # P(X <= 1) = .4609 > .25
pbinom(0, 5, 1/3)
[1] 0.1316872        # P(X <= 0) = .1317 < .25

qpois(.25, 5)
[1] 3
ppois(3, 5)
[1] 0.2650259
ppois(2, 5)
[1] 0.124652
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In short, there are different correct forms. However, I want to know if mine is one of the correct ones?

Comment: In short, I'm not absolutely sure I believe you have specified _any_ reasonable  method. Suppose $n = 5$ and observations are $x = (1, 3, 6, 11, 100).$ Looking for the first quartile, one of your formulas seems to give $6/4 = 1.5$ and the other $5/4 = 1.25.$ I guess that means the first quartile is somewhere between 1 and 3. The default method in R gives 3. It would be difficult to defend $2$ because then $4/5 > 75\%$ of data lie above $2.$ \\ The strategy of my answer was to try to give you a realistic view of how quartiles are found in practice. // Perhaps re-read @RossMillikan's Comment.